# Can we define nested projects in a SBT project?

Tags: scala, sbt, projects

We can define multi projects in a SBT project, like:

```
lazy val core = project in file("core")
lazy val web = project in file("web")
lazy val shared = project in file("shared")
```

But is it possible to define nested projects inside a sub project? Like:

```
lazy val nested = project in file("nested")
lazy val nested1 = project in file("nested/nested1")
lazy val nested2 = project in file("nested/nested2")
```

When I run `projects`, it will show all defined projects in flat list:

```
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/twer/workspace/sbt-dependency-export-plugin-test/
[info]     core
[info]     nested
[info]     nested1
[info]     nested2
[info]   * root
[info]     shared
[info]     web
```

This is not what I expected, actually, I want it to be a tree, like:

```
core
nested
   \-- nested1
   \-- nested2
root
shared
web
```

I want the `nested1` and `nested2` to be the sub projects of the `nested`, but not the whole project.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`projects` will always just show the project ids in a list.

But, I think, to do what you want you just need to do this:

```
lazy val nested = project in file("nested") aggregate (nested1, nested2)
```

Comment: for more details you can refer: https://pbassiner.github.io/blog/defining_multi-project_builds_with_sbt.html